# "The operation was cancelled" when trying to open files on my desktop

Tags: finder

There are some files on my desktop (a few png images and pdf files) that I can't open anymore using the Finder. Double-clicking the file icon brings up a [popup dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIde6.png) saying "The operation was cancelled".

I can still get the file contents using the Terminal, for example using `cat` or `vim` I can see the contents as binary data.

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

I'm currently on macOS Monterey 12.7.

Comment: If you sync the Desktop folder with iCloud, please disable that and try again. Any change?

Comment: @LincD. The files are not synced with iCloud.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, please log out and log back in. If there's no change, restart in Safe Mode, test while in that mode, and then restart as usual. Any change?

Comment: @LincD. Holding the shift button didn't have an effect while booting. However, after two failed attempts of rebooting into safe mode I found that the original problem somehow disappeared. Thanks, it's fixed now.